How do I access a Visual Basic 6.0 file?
I got an old Visual Basic 6.0 program with various files that I was asked to try to fix in some way. I figured the easiest way is to re-write the code in a different language but I can’t do that without being able to see the original code so I know what it was doing.
I have Visual Studio 2022 on my computer and while I know you can’t directly use that to open VB 6 files, is there a relatively easy way to even just see the code in some way.

With Notepad?..

If you purchase a Visual Studio Subscription you may have access to download VB6. You'll want to double check that it's still available prior to purchasing.

You can import module (.bas) and class (.cls) files into Excel.  As long as they're not using UI-based features, I would expect them to work correctly as the underlying language engine is the same heritage.


I have Visual Studio 2022 on my computer and while I know you can’t directly use that to open VB 6 files

This is not true.
Code files in almost any language, including VB6, can be opened in any text editor, whether Visual Studio, Notepad, Sublime, Atom, VSCode, XCode, Notepad++, vi/vim, emacs, gedit, nano, etc
This means Visual Studio 2022 is perfectly happy to open and edit a VB 6 file. It just won't be able to directly build or compile the result; it won't give you the level of intellisense and editing support you're used to. I do think you'll at least still get basic syntax highlighting, but I also can't promise you'll be able to just double-click the file in the Windows file browser (you may need to open the editor first, and then open the file from within the editor).
Even better news, you can also view .frm and .vbp files this way, though you won't get nice graphical previews.

Re syntax highlighting, there might be some holes for things from VBA-heritage VB which aren't in .NET-heritage VB.
